How to read only two numbers from python STDIN Function?
I want to take two numbers through the stdin python function and output their total.
import sys

num1 = None
num2 = None

print('Please Enter Two Numbers to Find their Sum or Enter q to quit')
for line in sys.stdin:
    if('q'==line.strip()):
        break
    else:
        num = int(line.strip())
        if(num1 == None):
            num1 = num
        elif(num2 == None):
            num2 = num
        else:
            break

total = num1 + num2
print(total)

I want the code to do the following:
Please Enter Two Numbers to Find their Sum or Enter q to quit    
12
11
23

When I run the above code it takes 3 numbers and then gives me the total of the first two numbers.
Please Enter Two Numbers to Find their Sum or Enter q to quit
12
11
13
23

I only want it to take 2 numbers and output their total. What do I need to change in the code to do so?

You might want to break immediately after having taken two numbers, not on the next iteration…? Also, don't do this complicated assignment to two variables; just use a list.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The issue is that your code continues to read input until it encounters a 'q' or until it has read three numbers. To fix this, you can modify the code to break out of the loop as soon as it has read two numbers. Here's the modified code:
import sys

num1 = None
num2 = None

print('Please Enter Two Numbers to Find their Sum or Enter q to quit')
for line in sys.stdin:
    if('q'==line.strip()):
        break
    else:
        num = int(line.strip())
        if(num1 == None):
            num1 = num
        elif(num2 == None):
            num2 = num
            break  # Break out of the loop after reading the second number

if num1 is not None and num2 is not None:
    total = num1 + num2
    print(total)
else:
    print("You didn't enter two numbers.")

In this modified code, the loop will break as soon as it has read two numbers, and then it will calculate and print their sum. If the user enters 'q' before entering two numbers, it will print a message indicating that they didn't enter two numbers.

@Rick. Sorry. It was my fault.

The answer you received is a good one.
An alternative could be to rejigger things and take advantage of python's structural pattern matching, which in my opinion can often make this kind of code easier to read (so long as the reader is familiar with SPM).
Here's what that might look like.
import sys

def validated_int(s):
    """Helper function returning a validated int from a string, otherwise just returns the string."""
    try: 
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

num1 = None
# this line not needed anymore:
# num2 = None

print('Please Enter Two Numbers to Find their Sum or Enter q to quit')
for line in sys.stdin:
    match validated_int(line.strip()), num1:
        case 'q', _:
            print("Quitting...")
            break
        case num2, int() if isinstance(num2, int):
            # num2 assigned
            total = num1 + num2
            print(total)
            break
        case _, int():
            # num1 was assigned, waiting for num2
            print("Invalid entry. Enter 'q' to quit.")
        case num1, _ if isinstance(num1, int):
            # num1 assigned
            continue
        case invalid:
            print("Invalid entry. Enter 'q' to quit.")
            continue

